# Integrate Eclipse RAP and OSGI/Spring-DM plugins, using Maven for build

Tags: eclipse, maven, springsource-dm-server, eclipse-rap, pax

**The background**
I have a project containing my domain model and persistence code (created using Spring-ROO). I've changed this into an OSGi bundle, and build & deploy it using Maven (via PAX Construct scripts). This bundle deploys nicely to Equinox, and I can access the various services,etc.

I also have a Eclipse RAP plugin/bundle from where I want to call the services/spring beans implemented by the domain bundle. And this is where things get interesting.

*The question(s):*

1) How do I setup the Eclipse RAP project to be build by Maven? I used the `mvn eclipse:to-maven` goal to get my Eclipse RAP target platform's plugins into my local repository, but when I use:

```
`pax-import-bundle -g org.eclipse.rap -a ui -v 1.3.0 -- -DimportTransitive -DwidenScope  `
```

I get this error:

> [INFO] [pax:import-bundle {execution: default-cli}]
>   [INFO] Importing Eclipse UI to com.propertyselldirect.propsell.build:provision:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
>   [INFO] Adding Eclipse UI as dependency to com.propertyselldirect:rap:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [ERROR] FATAL ERROR
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] version was null for org.eclipse.core:runtime
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Trace
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: version was null for org.eclipse.core:runtime
>       at    org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.getBaseVersion(DefaultArtifact.java:390)

I have also tried adding every eclipse runtime & rap dependency by hand, and then the project builds, but when I deploy to OSGi (using `pax-provision`) then most of the Eclipse RAP (and org.eclipse.core.runtime) plugins are not active. They are mostly listed as `INSTALLED`.

2) Alternatively, should I rather use the Eclipse PDE to build, and then include my domain plugin (and probably all the Spring-DM bundles) as dependencies. In this case, how would I (automatically) get Eclipse PDE to get access to those plugins/bundles, which would be deployed to my Maven repository? Do I install them manually to some target platform directoty, and make that my RAP target platform? (i.e. thus having the RAP target platform with all the Spring-DM bundles added).

I have many more questions, but will suffice with these for now.

Any pointers to useful documentation/articles on the web will be very welcome. I have googled, but not found anything specifically helpful.

Answer (score 1):

with some of my friends we create the dynaresume project (http://code.google.com/p/dynaresume/). Our main goal is to leverage best practices araund :
- Eclipse RCP
- Spring DM
- JPA

For the time being It works but It does not many things It's mainly a proof of concept

We try also to provide a Web Client such as Eclipse RAP.

I mavenized all this stuff using Maven 3/Tycho which is IMHO the easiest way to mavenize OSGi bundles.

I suppose we should keep in touch since we aiming the same goal.

Comment: sounds very interesting, and very much like I'm trying to do, except I'm also trying to leverage spring-roo for creating the entities (thus effectively using Spring, JPA and AOP for the entities). 
Will defintely have a look at your project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an OSGi expert but maybe have a look at [Introduction to OSGi with Pax, Maven, and Nexus Professional](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/07/introduction-to-osgi-with-pax-maven-and-nexus-professional/). It looks like Sonatype wrote some stuff on this subject.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look. OSGi bundles as such is not a problem for me, those I got going nicely using PAX and Maven, but the problem comes when adding the Eclipse RCP or RAP plugins to the mix...

Comment: @Herman I had a doubt when answering because I don't know RAP (do you build an Eclipse plugin at the end?). Just in case, check http://www.sonatype.com/people/2008/11/building-eclipse-plugins-with-maven-tycho/.